# How do I exclude a type externally from a registry scan that found it?

Tags: structuremap

Within a test I want to add a registry and then exclude a type that I know was found from the scan within the registry.  Here's the setup.

```
ObjectFactory.Configure(x =>
{
    x.AddRegistry<DefaultConventionsRegistry>();
    x.Scan(scanner => scanner.ExcludeType<RunBanks>());
});
```

Here's the registry:

```
public class DefaultConventionsRegistry : Registry
{
    public DefaultConventionsRegistry()
    {
        Scan(scanner =>
        {
            scanner.Assembly(AssemblyNames.WebAssemblyName);
            scanner.WithDefaultConventions();
            scanner.AddAllTypesOf<IHandles>();
        });
    }
}
```

RunBanks doesn't inherit directly from IHandles.  It inherits from an abstract base class that inherits from a open generic interface which finally inherits from IHandles.

I'm expecting the RunBanks to be excluded from the container but if I call

```
ObjectFactory.GetAllInstances<IHandles>();
```

An instance of the RunBanks type exists.  If I explicitly exclude the RunBanks type within the DefaultConventionsRegistry then things work as expected but I don't want to do that.

Comment: could you provide your class structures?

Comment: @Rookian Thanks for your reply! I'm not sure what else you would need to see. What do you mean by class structure?  The point here is that I have a test that Configures SM to add a registry (as shown). It also defines the fact that SM should exclude a certain type (RunBanks).  The registry scans for all types of an interface.  That RunBanks type (that was explicitly excluded) inherits from IHandles but I'm expecting it to not be initialized when calling GetAllInstances<IHandles>() but it is. If I'm still not being clear, let me know and I'll show you a test that is failing when I have time.

Comment: Are the different implementations in different assemblies?

Answer (score 0):

I'm going to verify this later but I have a feeling that the reason the exclusion of the specific type isn't working is because I'm not telling the assembly where to scan. I'll update this answer later when I find out for sure.

Comment: looks like that didn't fix it.  I'm still stumped here.